# How to use form's function in other class C#

Tags: c#, oop

I've got a Form and class. In form I call a function from object which must make some output while it's work. How can I do that?

```
namespace Gui
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        void PaintGui()//functioun which change the data in gui
        {

        }

        private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //object of some class
            //function from this object which should call PaintGui() while it working
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you saying that you don't know how to call the `PaintGui()` method when you click a button..? you need to edit your question and write it so that it makes more sense.. thanks

Comment: No, i need to call a PaintGui() method in function from other class.

Comment: _'while it's work'_ Assuming that the gui isn't updated when you're doing long running work in the `btnCalc_Click`. Try `Label1.Update()` in your `PaintGui()` _(if you're using a Label)_

Comment: then show us the class and it's definition / namespace.. do you not now how to reference another method from within your existing class..? it's not that difficult.. but show us the other class and it will help in the guessing game

Comment: No, I need to make some output from non-form function

Comment: Pass your form instance to that other class' method and better yet, extract an interface having the PaintGui() method, let your form implement that interface, and make that other class' method accept a parameter of type of your new interface and pass your form to that method with "this".

Comment: To access a non-static member of a class, you need a reference to an instance of that class. For your other class to have such a reference, you will need to give it one. There are lots of ways to do this; as many ways to do this as there are ways to copy a value from one variable to another. Please see the marked duplicate for one of the more common ways to do this given your problem statement (such as it is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're meaning to pass a method as parameter, so the method can execute it as a *callback*. You should pass a method (without the parenthesis) to the other class and It must match the `Action<>` definition.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public void PaintGui(int percent)
    {
        Label1.Text = percent.ToString() + "% completed";
        Label1.Update();
    }

    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //object of some class
        OtherClass other = new OtherClass();
        other.DoWork(PaintGui);
    }
}
```

---

```
// FOR EXAMPLE
public class OtherClass
{
    public void DoWork(Action<int> action)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<=100;i++)
        {
            action(i);
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }
}
```